# Driving MOSFET with load on source

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I would like to know what circuitry I will need in order to drive a N-Channel MOSFET (IRF1405) with the load placed on the source.

From my understanding the laod is placed on the drain however I would like to build a H-bridge driver with ONLY N channel mosfets. The high side mosfets of the bridge would therefor require some method of driving the MOSFETS properly.

Comment: A typical MOSFFET H-bridge. You need a mosfet/igbt driver with separated psu or to use bootstraping technique. look for IR2112 and similar. Keep in mind that bootstraping needs switching of transitors all the time, so maybe you can't acheive 100% duty cycle ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an appropriate driver. Here's just one of the many available: -

[image]

It basically works like this: -

[image]

It creates a voltage (Vboot) that is several volts higher than Vbat. This allows it to properly drive an N channel MOSFET used in the upper half of a half or full bridge motor controller.

Comment: Not to be overly annoying, but I'd like to add the minimum switching frequency requirement for the bootstrap by way of this comment. It's only visible in a tiny hidden corner of the typical application "6Hz to ..." and the OP _might_ be hunting for near-DC functionality. In which case, of course, a separate 5V booster circuit can be used to supply the boost pin of most of these drivers with "Vcc + 5V".

Comment: @Asmyldof good point - my answer assumes that the H bridge is being toggled quite regularly a la PWM.

Comment: It is the most common to use PWM. I only note it, because I have recently been required to include some all-N H-bridges for polarity control in a design and very quickly decided on a VQFN H-bridge driver as you suggest, but with a tiny SOT23-6 cap-cap booster to make 17V on the 12V system for the BOOTSTR pin.

Comment: @Asmyldof could you elaborate futher on how I can do this using a Bootstr pin? I think this might be the better approach for my application

Comment: @user3095420 _exactly_ as I described. You make a voltage 5V above the supply _if, and only if_ your driver device supports that and connect that to the boost pin in stead of the capacitor.

Comment: @user3095420 Probably the simplest way to do this is buy an isolating DC to DC converter and connect the secondary dc negative terminal to the Vbat postion. The positive from the DC converter is then (say) 12V above Vbat and can connect to Vboot.